# C++ - Working with Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

> The Motor vehicle Administration has asked you to write a program that
>   grades the written portion of the Driver’s License exam. The Exam has
>   a 20 multiple choice questions with the answers for the questions 1…20
>   respectively shown in the list below;

```
A   B   D   A   B   B   B   C   C   D   A   C   C   C   D   A   B   D   D   B
```

> It is assumed that a total of 10 students take the exam each day. Your program should store the correct answer shown above in an Array.
>   It should then ask each student’s answer for the 20 questions and the
>   answers should be stored in another array. After the answers have been
>   entered, the program should display a message indicating whether a
>   student passed or failed the exam.(A student must correctly answer  18
>   out of 20 questions to  pass the exam).It should then display the
>   total number of correctly answered questions and the  total number of
>   incorrectly answered questions by each student. Your program should
>   also display the percent of students who passed the test in a given
>   day.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declare variables and constants
    int correctAnswers = 0;
    const int QUESTIONS = 20;
    char answers[QUESTIONS] = {'A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C',  'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'B'};

    for(int count = 0; count < QUESTIONS; count++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter your answer for Question " << (count + 1) << endl;
        cin >> answers;
    }
    if(answers[0] == 'A')
    {
        correctAnswers++;
    }
    else if(answers[1] = 'B')
    {
        correctAnswers++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I have begun to write this code for the problem statement listed above. This is what I have so far. I started making if statements for each of the answers, and if they inputted the correct answer, the result will add 1 to the counter. My question is, Is there a better way to get the users answers and check to see if they are correct, or is what I am doing now, the best way to do it?

Comment: To start with, you need to store each answer in the appropriate member of the array.

Comment: cin >> answers; just destroyed your nice answers array. YOu need to store the answers in a different array (student_asnwers for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specification you must store the list of correct answers in an array. the answer of each student must be too saved in an array. After getting the answers of a student you can iterate over the answers and compare them with the expected answers.

```
  char correct_answers[QUESTIONS] = {'A', 'B', 'D','A','B', 'B','B','C','C', 'D','A','C' ,'C' , 'C' ,'D' ,'A' ,'B','D', 'D',  'B'};
    char answers[QUESTIONS];
    for(int count = 0; count < QUESTIONS; count++) {
        cout << "Please enter your answer for Question " << (count + 1) << endl;
        cin >> (answers+count);
    }

    for(int count = 0; count < QUESTIONS; count++) {
        if(answers[count] == correct_answers[count]) {
            correctAnswers++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets see.. you want to cin on something else, not answers because then your overwriting what you set as the Answer Key!

When you look you check answers[count] == inputValue from cin.

basically..  some pseudo code..

```
char inputValue;

loop ..
    cin << inputValue;
    answers[count] == inputValue  ...  
        Then ++correctAnswer ...
```